# Paperclip uploads 404ing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip

I'm not sure if I understand how Paperclip works, but as far as I can tell, the default place to save uploads is in the /public folder. When I upload my photo on my development, they appear correctly in (and I can open them in the file structure):

```
/public/bookmarks/:id/:style.:extension
```

However, when I do `bookmark.photo.url`, I get something like:

```
/system/bookmarks/thumbs/000/000/042/original/filename.png?1362768439
```

Here's my `bookmark.rb`:

```
has_attached_file   :photo,
                        :styles => { :medium => ["512x512>", :jpg], :thumb => ["200x200#", :jpg] }
                        :default_url => "public/bookmarks/default/:style.png",
                        :path => "assets/content/bookmarks/:id/:style.:extension"
```

Am I missing something here? Isn't Paperclip meant to deal with this stuff for me, or have I got something wrong in the config?

UPDATE

If I add the `:path` and `:url` in the first answer, I get:

```
<img src="/assets/bookmarks/44/original.jpg?1362775508">
```

Whereas I should be getting:

```
<img src="/bookmarks/44/original.jpg?1362775508">
```

But, if I comment out the `:url` option, instead of getting:

[image: This, which is the default size]

this, which is the default not-found image size, I get:

[image]

this, which is the same width as the image I have on my filesystem, but the wrong height, and not found. This happens in both Chrome and Safari with clean caches. When I go to the URL, I get a 404. I can also confirm that the image is stored correctly on the filesystem and is viewable from the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe it's a little weird. I suggest you set both :url and :path in a way similar to this:

```
url: '/:class/:id/:style.:extension',
path: ':rails_root/public:url'
```

This means images will be stored in:

```
"#{Rails.root}/public/bookmarks/:id/:style.:extension"
```

And the URL will give you something like:

```
/bookmarks/bookmarks/1/thumbs.png
```

Note that you can do this using `config.paperclip_defaults` in "application.rb", so you don't have to do it on each model. And you can override this on "production.rb" if you want a different path or storage, e.g.:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = config.paperclip_defaults.merge({
    storage: :s3,
    path: 'project_name/public:url'
  })
```

Comment: That's nearly working, thanks. Except now I get `<img src="/assets/bookmarks/44/original.jpg?1362775508">` not `<img src="/bookmarks/44/original.jpg?1362775508">`

Comment: Maybe I should just symlink it into the assets folder?

Comment: And your images are correctly stored in `"#{Rails.root}/public/bookmarks/:id/:style.:extension"`?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. It's just getting the URL of them that isn't quite right.

Comment: Have you tried `pry` and `pry-debugger`, get into URL method, it should be clear when "/assets/" is being added and maybe why? All this happens in https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb (url, path_options, interpolate, etc.)

Comment: I'll add to my question with some more info.

Comment: This worked correctly - I'd forgotten to restart the `delayed_job` worker, that was still referencing the old code.

Comment: If the behavior is a "little weird", then it is a bug and it still occurs to this very day.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me recently. I was getting a 404 because I had `:style` instead of `:styles` in `/app/models/mymodel.rb`

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```